# collect all selected radio button of some tab pages

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oop, devexpress, windows-forms-designer

I have about 18 tab page, each tab has some radio button.
I want to collect all selected radio button into a DB.
how can I collect them?
i have a button below the form for go forward next tab with colde below:

```
private void simpleButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        var TabIndex = tabOrthpedic.SelectedTabPageIndex;
        if (TabIndex == tabOrthpedic.TabPages.Count - 1)
        {
            return;
        }
        tabOrthpedic.SelectedTabPageIndex += 1;
 }
```

also I created an object for selected radio button of each tab as below:

```
      public class Profile
{
   public string ProfileNumber;
   public string PainOrgan;
   public string NeckLoc;
   public string BackLoc;
   public string LowBackLoc;
   public string ShoulderLoc;
   public string ElbowLoc;
   public string HandLoc;
   public string PelvicLoc;
   public string KneeLoc;
   public string FootLoc;
   public string PainRate;
   public string PainTime;
   public string PainHistory;
   public string PainResult;
   public string Follow;
   public string Expectation;
   public string Limitation;
   public string DesieseHistory;
}
```

Comment: any own ideas? what's the point of those strings btw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following class to your project. Using `Descendants` ensures that if there are other containers on the tab control with radio buttons we can get to them too.

```
public static class ControlExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Descendants<T>(this Control control) where T : class
    {
        foreach (Control child in control.Controls)
        {
            if (child is T thisControl)
            {
                yield return (T)thisControl;
            }

            if (child.HasChildren)
            {
                foreach (T descendant in Descendants<T>(child))
                {
                    yield return descendant;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public static RadioButton RadioButtonChecked(this Control control, bool @checked = true) 
        => control.Descendants<RadioButton>().ToList().FirstOrDefault((radioButton) => radioButton.Checked == @checked);
}
```

Usage

```
foreach (TabPage page in tabControl1.TabPages)
{
    RadioButton selected = page.RadioButtonChecked();
    if (selected is not null)
    {
        //  We have a selected RadioButton
    }
    else
    {
        // no selected RadioButton on TabPage
    }
}
```

Note: this is for conventional Windows Forms controls, don't know about DevExpress.

[Full source](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/q-a-questions/blob/master/WindowsFormsLibrary/LanguageExtensions/ControlExtensions.cs)